# MongoDB updateOne

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to update an existing Mongo record, but am getting an *"Additional information: Element name 'ID' is not valid'."* error

I have a a BsonDocument "document" containing data that I retrieve from another source that looks like this:

```
{ "ID" : "ABCecdcf9851efbf0ef66953", ListingKey : "234534345345", "Created" : ISODate("2017-08-04T00:31:23.357Z"), "Modified" : ISODate("2017-08-04T00:31:23.358Z"), "Field1" : 1, "Field2" : "0.09", "Field3" : "1.10", "Field4" : "1", "Field5" : "1" }
```

Here is the C# code that I have written:

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("MyCollection");                              

//Hard coded for testing
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("ListingKey", "234534345345");

collection.UpdateOne(filter, document);
```

Is this related to the BsonDocument that I am trying to use to update? I found this documentation, which causes me to think that this is the cause. If so, is there a way to do an update with the format I have been provided?

https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/update/

I had a process working where it would delete the document and then add a new document, but for efficiency's sake I need this to update. Ideally it will only update the fields that are present in the BsonDocument and keep the existing fields in the Mongo document as is.

Comment: What is the actual content of `document`? If it actually looks exactly like you list above then `ISODate` is not a valid argument as there is no such object constructor in C#. You probably have a JSON string or just a "string" for that property. Hence the error.

Comment: @NeilLunn I assume that it's a json string. It's failing on the first element (ID). I'll update the question with better data. This field is not an ObjectId or anything special in Mongo.

Comment: Well I "assume" as much as well. But no-one can actually be sure unless you present the "full context" of what you are trying to do here. Which is what I asked for and why I asked it. So please [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45496613/edit) with the required detail that is asked for.

Comment: @NeilLunn. Sorry, I see how it's worded poorly. The top block of code it what's in the document variable.

Comment: { "ID" : "ABCecdcf9851efbf0ef66953", ListingKey : "234534345345", "Created" : ISODate("2017-08-04T00:31:23.357Z"), "Modified" : ISODate("2017-08-04T00:31:23.358Z"), "Field1" : 1, "Field2" : "0.09", "Field3" : "1.10", "Field4" : "1", "Field5" : "1" }

Comment: Looks like second argument is supposed to be an Update Builders<BsonDocument>.Update variable instead of a JSON document, to replace the whole document there is ReplaceOneAsync method

Answer (score 11):

My problem was because I did not have the correct value when trying to update. My code works with this:

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("MyCollection");                              

//Hard coded for testing
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("ListingKey", "234534345345");

var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("Created", DateTime.UtcNow);
foreach (BsonElement item in document)
{
    update = update.Set(item.Name, item.Value);
}
var result = collection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
```

I had to convert my string into an update BsonDocument.

Comment: I had a case with class (bank-account) that could be inserted if it was a new "account" after converting it with ToBsonDocument() (then inserted with collection.InsertOne() ), while if it was not a new "account" it could be updated just like you show with Filter and Update, and I didn't need the foreach loop (and I didn't understand what <document> was). Thanks @ferensilver